# How to obtain information from xml digital signature (.cer file) in C#?

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am using service that returns the XML signature. now my task is to identify the signer name from response xml signature.

XML response signature format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EsignResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resCode="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" status="1" ts="2019-05-02T15:15:13" txn="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
   <UserX509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</UserX509Certificate>
   <Signatures>
      <DocSignature error="" id="1" sigHashAlgorithm="SHA256">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DocSignature>
   </Signatures>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
               <Modulus>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Modulus>
               <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
         </KeyValue>
         <X509Data>
            <X509SubjectName>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</X509SubjectName>
            <X509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
</EsignResp>
```

In `<UserX509Certificate>` tag I get certificate details like **Issued to,Issued By, Valid From**.

Is there any way to get these information using itextsharp(C#).

Comment: You said that you can get certificate details like Issued to,Issued By, Valid From from the Cert. In what way ?

Comment: I mean how do i get that information from xml signature

Comment: when create .cer file from Userx509Certificate I can see that info in siganture info section

Answer (score 0):

You don't need itestsharp for handling and parsing certificates. It's all about pdf and not required for xml.

You may convert Base64 string in  to X509Certificate2 type using below code.

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MII<...>==");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

Then cert variable above will have properties like

```
cert.Issuer or cert.IssuerName
cert.Subject or cert.SubjectName
```

The content may be parsed by split(',').split('=') as per your requirement.